# Is it possible to restrict the user from re-sizing a UWP app?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-10, uwp

I am trying to port my existing WP8 app to Windows-10. Planning to release it in phases with just WP10 as primary target for phase-1. However I want to be able to release the same/slightly-scaled-up UI to desktop as well in phase-1. I have been playing around with a sample app trying to restrict window resizing by handling `CoreWindow's SizeChanged` event and preventing it from propagating. However this doesn't seem to do it for me. I am now wondering is it possible to restrict the user from re-sizing a UWP app at all? Any help/pointers would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

[PreferredLaunchViewSize](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.viewmanagement.applicationview.preferredlaunchviewsize.aspx) and [PreferredLaunchWindowingMode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.viewmanagement.applicationview.preferredlaunchwindowingmode.aspx) should helps to pre set the screen size. [SetPreferredMinSize](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.viewmanagement.applicationview.setpreferredminsize.aspx) is used to set the minimum size of the app window.

Personally I don't think its a good practice to restrict the window size of the app since everything should under user's control.

Anyway [TryResizeView | tryResizeView method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.viewmanagement.applicationview.tryresizeview.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) should help to resize the app size.