# disable app sizing for a Universal Windows App

Tags: wpf, win-universal-app, sizing

I am looking for a way to disable Window sizing for a universal Windows app, something like a fixed size dialog box from the pre WPF days.

Comment: Possible duplicate [Is it possible to restrict the user from re-sizing a UWP app?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32212301/is-it-possible-to-restrict-the-user-from-re-sizing-a-uwp-app)

Comment: What you want to do is not re-sizing the window but disable the user operation on re-sizing the window by mouse, right?

Answer (score 0):

That's it's possible because of UWP is for varied size devices. But you can set preffered size in MainPage constructor with code like:

```
ApplicationView.PreferredLaunchViewSize = new Size { Height = 550, Width = 360 };
ApplicationView.PreferredLaunchWindowingMode = ApplicationViewWindowingMode.PreferredLaunchViewSize;
```